# Simple Binding question, unable to bind to button command in a DataTemplate using MVVM Light Toolkit

Tags: silverlight, binding, datatemplate, mvvm-light

I've been attempting to bind to buttons within a DataTemplate without much success. The button does not fire.  Button Click works successfully outside of the DataTemplate.  Yet if I create a Click="button_click" the click button is fired.  The Button Content binds perfectly as well.

Example to illustrate..

Why does the command not fire?  Advice on how this should be handled this?  The example is a simplified version of my real problem, I am currently not using a Listbox.  I only recreated the same problem with a listbox..

Comment: Can you paste u r code please, the one by which you r using the command and doing it.

Comment: That's weird, I pasted it.  I'll build up another example.

Comment: <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cars, Mode=TwoWay}">

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>


                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding AddButtonCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />


                    </DataTemplate>

                    
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                
                
            </ListBox>

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  Strangely enough the original example is in the body of the question when I go to edit it.  

Just seems strange that the button gets the content binding but not the command binding.   And again I use the very same button in a canvas right above it.  I was hoping to bind a command parm that included some kind of object key... but no dice on even getting the event to fire.

Comment: DataContext is switching isn't it..

Comment: <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding DataContext.AddButtonCommand, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />

of course.. duh..  :)  That's the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question once before, came up with the answer myself, see this question:

[How to connect a Button in a Silverlight ListItem DataTemplate, in a ResourceDictionary (Styles.xaml), with a handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118395/how-to-connect-a-button-in-a-silverlight-listitem-datatemplate-in-a-resourcedict)

> The solution seems to be to use
>   'nested' ViewModels here:
>
> In other words, rather than have my
>   ListBox bind directly to a collection
>   of DTOs/business objects (as I was
>   doing above) I instead created a
>   simple ViewModel to wrap each DTO, and
>   have the command on it, rather than on
>   the original, top-level VM.

This seem like a sln?

Comment: Yup it is for sure.  I actually ended up implementing the exact same thing.  The real problem I had was with a panel control, and I wanted to remove a panel using a button on the panel.  Using the parents view model bindings became less than clean in my opinion.  Required a key or index to bind to on the command parm, and I'd rather just not use a command parm at all.  Every time I think about using it, I question my method of attack.  Usually if I need it, I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks for the reply.