# How to Call an Event of Control that is present inside a Custom Control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a Custom Cntrol that has a button inside it. Now I want to access the button click from my Application Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this Post:

[How to Access a Button present inside a Custom Control, from the implementing page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690177/how-to-access-a-button-present-inside-a-custom-control-from-the-implementing-pag)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways:

You can access the button's click event through the user control object. For eg.

```
MyUC.button1.click += //etc
```

You can create your custom event of that specific button click in the user control. For example, in your usercontrol, you have:

```
public delegate void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e);

public event OnButtonClick Button1Click;


button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Button1Click != null) 
       Button1Click(this, e);

}
```

Then you watch for that event on your user control:

```
MyUC.Button1Click += //etc.
```